# How to create a custom discount “Gift card” in Magento 1.9 at cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, custom, discount, gift-card

The functionality will be =

1. Enter Gift Card number(16 digit)
2. Enter Gift Card Pin(6 digit)
3. Enter Amount(amount entered by user)

I have already created the above mentioned input fields in the cart page.but dont know how to proceed further.

website: https://www.happyvalleytea.com/

cart page view: https://www.happyvalleytea.com/checkout/cart/ (add any product to cart)

When the user clicks on gift card apply button, the transaction will happen on a 3rd party vendor(via curl api call). The response received from the api should be used as a discount amount on the cart page.